# Install Dot net 4.5 silently as adependency

Tags: c#, installation, silent-installer

I have a setup that install silently but it has dependency of dot net framework 4.5, so how can i create 
a installer that installs dependency silently also.

```
   Setup is created in Install Shield and it is  a wpf application
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need admin access for installing the framework, have you already got that to install your app?

Comment: In case of my application i get it, i want to know that if there is any way to install framework silently.  And yes i got the permission for admin.

Comment: And i cannot bundle the framework exe with my application because my setup size is only 4 mb and framework size is almost 50 mb.

Comment: If you have admin all is golden. If your setup had been low rights, then it would have been a tad more work. ie if you had requested admin access to install .net and then ran your setup in the same context, the admin user would have got your app. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to use a command line like

```
dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart
```

Use the web bootstrapper to download the Framework online

Maybe have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/16/9553804.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx)

Edit: Just see that you don't want to include .net 4.5 setup...
Edit: Code fixed

Comment: actually above command are useful when we have setup, but what if i want to install exe on client side

Comment: I mean when i give my setup to anyone then how it is possible to install application and framework both install silently

Comment: You can download the web installer. For 4.5, it is named dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe. It is < 1MB and it installs .net 4.5 online. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is your need,Just change download path i find it with registry if silverlight install or not it will check u can do same with .net framework and if it's not exist automatically download and sliently install through temp file.Download in Temp and install from temp :)

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;


namespace ControlPanel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ControlPanelFinal.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ControlPanelFinal : Window
    {
        private readonly BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        public ControlPanelFinal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SilverLightInstall();
            _bw.DoWork += _bw_DoWork;
            _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += _bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            _bw.ProgressChanged += _bw_ProgressChanged;
           // _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        void _bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void _bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                this.textblock1.Text = "Completed";
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                this.textblock1.Text = ("Error :" + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                progressbar1.Maximum = 100;
                progressbar1.Minimum = 1;
                progressbar1.Value = progressbar1.Maximum;
                textblock1.Text = "Completed";
            }

        }

        void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);

            }
            string filepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Silverlight.exe");
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /q  /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", filepath);
            p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            p.Start();

        }
        private void SilverLightInstall()
        {
            var Key1 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft";
            using (var regKey1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(Key1))
            {
                if (regKey1.GetSubKeyNames().Contains("Silverlight"))
                {
                    textblock1.Text = "Install";
                    checkbox1.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkbox1.IsEnabled = true;
                    string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Silverlight.exe");
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Error");
                    }
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/8/C/F8C0EACB-92D0-4722-9B18-965DD2A681E9/30514.00/Silverlight_x64.exe"), filename);
                }
            }

        }

        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            textblock2.Text = " Download Completed";
            btnInstall.IsEnabled = true;

        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnInstall.IsEnabled = false;
            double byteIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = byteIn / totalBytes * 100;
            textblock2.Text = "Download " + e.BytesReceived / 1024 + " Of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024;
            progressbar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bw.IsBusy == false)
            {
                _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```