# How to create an installer for Visual Studio C# WPF project using wixsharp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.6, wixsharp

I want to create an installer with wixsharp for my visual studio `c # WPF application`.
In order for the user to install my application, I have to check if `.NET 4.6` is installed or not.

If this is the case, I proceed with the installation otherwise, I must install `.NET 4.6` in silent mode (the user must click next to install the `.NET`, after that proceed to install my application with a other next)

This is the first time I am creating an installer for an application and I have no any idea about that. so how to do that using wixsharp.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the CLR Version using `Environment.Version` property.
Below you can read more about relationship between the CLR version and the .NET Framework's version itself:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to install .NET Framework sillently in the background then you can just run the Installer's exe with additional `/q` just like in the answer from this question:
[Install Dot net 4.5 silently as adependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942554/install-dot-net-4-5-silently-as-adependency?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Ohh thank you very much ... But how to create the installer it self ?

Comment: Well you tagged the 'wixsharp' in the question, so I thought you know how to use it. You can watch some tutorials for it or try examples from the project's repository here:

https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp